# AngularJS: how come my ng-options don't show up?

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs

I am using AngularJS. I have a  dropdown. All the ng-options exist in the dropdown, and when selected they display the correct output, but their name is not displayed.

I think it's something in the ng-options value, but I haven't been able to figure it out.

view snippet:

```
    <select ng-options="ciudad as ciudad.tiendas.code for ciudad in ciudades" ng-model="ciudadElegida"></select>

    <div class="tiendasContainer">
        <article class="tienda" ng-repeat="tienda in ciudadElegida.tiendas">
            <h4>{{tienda.nombre}}</h4> 
            <h4>{{tienda.dir1}}</h4>            
        </article>
    </div>
```

controller snippet - object that feeds ng-options:

```
$scope.ciudades = [  
                {
                    code: "Barranquilla", 
                    tiendas: [
                        {
                            "nombre":"C.C. Unico Outlet",
                            "dir1":"Local 22",
                            "dir2":""
                        }               
                    ]
                },
                {
                    code: "Bogota", 
                    tiendas: [
                        {
                            "nombre":"Calle 13",
                            "dir1":"Carrera 60 #12-55",
                            "dir2":""
                        },
                        {
                            "nombre":"C.C. Floresta Outlet",
                            "dir1":"Local 121",
                            "dir2":""
                        },
                        {
                            "nombre":"C.C. Plaza Imperial",
                            "dir1":"Local 137",
                            "dir2":""
                        },
                        {
                            "nombre":"Zona Industrial",
                            "dir1":"Avenida Calle 9 #60-70",
                            "dir2":"Local 10"
                        },
                        {
                            "nombre":"Galerias",
                            "dir1":"Carrera 24 #53-96",
                            "dir2":""
                        },
                        {
                            "nombre":"C.C. Santa Fe",
                            "dir1":"Local 1-90",
                            "dir2":""
                        },
                        {
                            "nombre":"C.C. Unicentro de Occidente",
                            "dir1":"Local 115",
                            "dir2":""
                        },
                        {
                            "nombre":"C.C. Gran Estacion",
                            "dir1":"Local 1-020",
                            "dir2":""
                        }
                    ]
                },
                {
                    code: "Cali", 
                    tiendas: [
                        {
                            "nombre":"C.C. Unicentro",
                            "dir1":"Local 225",
                            "dir2":""
                        },
                        {
                            "nombre":"C.C. Jardin Plaza",
                            "dir1":"Local 178",
                            "dir2":""
                        },
                        {
                            "nombre":"C.C. Cosmocentro",
                            "dir1":"Local 2M",
                            "dir2":""
                        },
                        {
                            "nombre":"C.C. Chipichape",
                            "dir1":"Local 5-10",
                            "dir2":""
                        },
                        {
                            "nombre":"C.C. La 14 de Calima",
                            "dir1":"Local 1-154",
                            "dir2":""
                        },
                        {
                            "nombre":"C.C. Unico",
                            "dir1":"Local 214",
                            "dir2":""
                        },
                        {
                            "nombre":"Plaza de Caicedo",
                            "dir1":"Carrera 4 #12-70",
                            "dir2":""
                        },
                        {
                            "nombre":"C.C. Palmetto",
                            "dir1":"Local 147",
                            "dir2":""
                        },
                    ]
                },
                {
                    code: "Cartago", 
                    tiendas: [
                        {
                            "nombre":"C.C. El Virrey",
                            "dir1":"Local 18",
                            "dir2":""
                        }               
                    ]
                },
                {
                    code: "Florencia", 
                    tiendas: [
                        {
                            "nombre":"C.C. Gran Plaza",
                            "dir1":"Local 149",
                            "dir2":""
                        }               
                    ]
                },
                {
                    code: "Girardot", 
                    tiendas: [
                        {
                            "nombre":"Centro",
                            "dir1":"Carrera 10 #14-86",
                            "dir2":""
                        }               
                    ]
                },
                {
                    code: "Ibague", 
                    tiendas: [
                        {
                            "nombre":"C.C. Multicentro",
                            "dir1":"Local 137",
                            "dir2":""
                        }               
                    ]
                },
                {
                    code: "Ipiales", 
                    tiendas: [
                        {
                            "nombre":"C.C. Gran Plaza Ipiales",
                            "dir1":"Local 1-073",
                            "dir2":""
                        }               
                    ]
                },
                {
                    code: "Monteria", 
                    tiendas: [
                        {
                            "nombre":"C.C. Alamedas",
                            "dir1":"Local B-140",
                            "dir2":""
                        }               
                    ]
                },
                {
                    code: "Palmira", 
                    tiendas: [
                        {
                            "nombre":"C.C. Llano Grande",
                            "dir1":"Local 316",
                            "dir2":""
                        },
                        {
                            "nombre":"C.C. Unicentro",
                            "dir1":"Local 146",
                            "dir2":""
                        },  
                        {
                            "nombre":"Plaza Bolivar",
                            "dir1":"Carrera 30 #30-69",
                            "dir2":""
                        },
                        {
                            "nombre":"Centro",
                            "dir1":"Calle 31 #26-14",
                            "dir2":""
                        }               
                    ]
                },
                {
                    code: "Pasto", 
                    tiendas: [
                        {
                            "nombre":"C.C. Unicentro",
                            "dir1":"Local 1-19",
                            "dir2":""
                        },
                        {
                            "nombre":"C.C. Unico",
                            "dir1":"Local 45",
                            "dir2":""
                        },  
                        {
                            "nombre":"C.C. Sebastian de Belalcazar",
                            "dir1":"Local 1",
                            "dir2":""
                        }               
                    ]
                },
                {
                    code: "Pereira", 
                    tiendas: [
                        {
                            "nombre":"Centro",
                            "dir1":"Carrera 6 #19-16",
                            "dir2":""
                        }               
                    ]
                },
                {
                    code: "Soledad", 
                    tiendas: [
                        {
                            "nombre":"C.C. Gran Plaza del Sol",
                            "dir1":"Local 148",
                            "dir2":""
                        }               
                    ]
                },
                {
                    code: "Villavicencio", 
                    tiendas: [
                        {
                            "nombre":"C.C. Unico",
                            "dir1":"Local 31",
                            "dir2":""
                        },
                        {
                            "nombre":"C.C. Viva Exito",
                            "dir1":"Local 151A",
                            "dir2":""
                        }               
                    ]
                },
            ];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to your `json`: `ciudad.tiendas.code` doesn't exist, you probably wanted to do this instead:

```
<select ng-options="ciudad as ciudad.code for ciudad in ciudades" ng-model="ciudadElegida"></select>
```

Comment: wow. duh. thank you. do you know how I can select a default value for this dropdown? Angular shows a blank as default.

Comment: sure, in your controller do this: $scope.ciudadElegida=$scope.ciudades[0] for instance